# Как сравнить данные с записью в базе MySQL?

Tags: php, mysqli, update

Как правильно сравнить данные с записью в базе MySQL, и обновить в случае несоответствия? Вот мой пример, может есть вариант получше?

```
<?
$newData = 'Тест';

  if ($select = $mysqli->query('SELECT phone_number from users WHERE id=172')) {

      $row = $select->fetch_assoc();

  }

  if($row['phone_number'] != $newData) {

     $update = $mysqli->query('UPDATE users SET phone_number = "'.$newData.'" WHERE id=172');

     echo 'Запись обновлена';

  } 

  else {

    echo 'Ничего не делаем';

  }

?>
```

Comment: как вы сами начали делать это? покажите фрагмент кода

Comment: какие данные? с чем несоответствуют?

Comment: @Saidolim,  Добавил фрагмент кода.

Comment: @Dmitry V, Новые данные которые к примеру указал пользователь, с теми данными что уже есть в БД? Чем плох указанный мною способ?

Comment: Ваш метод плох как минимум тем, что между SELECT  и UPDATE может произойти еще что-нибудь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю зачем доставать данные из базы для сравнения, если для целей оптимизации апдейтов - то это сильно не поможет, если только предыдущие значения данных или их хеш не хранить где нибудь отдельно или не передавать в форму пользователя и потом принимать обратно.
Но если есть цель просто не допустить лишних дисковых операций по фиксации транзакции, записи в транзакционный журнал, то можно сразу дать апдейт с условиями.

```
$mysqli->query('UPDATE users SET phone_number = "'.$newData.
              '" WHERE id=172 AND phone_number <> "'.$newData.'"');

if($mysqli->affected_rows>0): echo "Данные изменены"; endif;
```

Comment: прав. Этот вариант намного лучше и надежнее. Голосую за него.

Comment: Доставать данные незачем (как я уже понял), просто до этого не знал про способ указанный вами, поэтому и спрашиваю здесь.

Comment: Если данные совпадают то запрос не выполнится, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Скажем так, запрос в базу уйдет, база заглянет в таблицу, проверит условия, увидит, что условия where не выполнились (<> дало false) и на этом закончит. Ну или если данные другие тут же и подправит запись, пока она у нее в памяти, только что выбранная

Comment: Все теперь разобрался, благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

В принципе Вы все правильно сделали.

- Берете из базы текущую запись
- Сравниваете с данными от пользователя
- если разные  - обновляете.

Все правильно.

---

А можно еще чуть по другому: в первом запросе сравнение делать.

```
if ($select = $mysqli->query('SELECT phone_number FROM users WHERE id=172 AND phone_number <> "'.$newData.'"')) {
```

Если этот запрос Вам вернет запись, значит надо обновлять.

Но опять же - Ваш вариант тоже правильный.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Мне кажется что ваш вариант лучше так-как выглядит более коротко.

Comment: @ВадимПедченко Вашу правку я принял, однако хочу обратить внимание, что не суть важно что именно возвращает запрос. Мы лишь проверяем наличие строки. Так что вернет он `id` или `phone_number` - не суть важно. Мы проверяем наличие возврата как такового...

Comment: Я понимаю) Изменил просто для наглядности.